# How to convert java.util.Date to String

Tags: java, date

I hava a value-object,like this:

```
public Class User{
    int id;
    Date birthDay;
    ...
}
```

when i call `user.getBirthDay()`,i want return a string like this:

```
2014-10-16 10:10:10
```

How to convert?

Comment: Which Java version are you using ?

Comment: @alfasin centos + open-jdk 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code:

```
public String getBirthDay(){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
    return sdf.format(birthDay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java 7 and below you can use `SimpleDateFormat` in order to format the `Date` object:

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(df.format(date)); // prints 2014-06-16 20:06:13
```

And if you're using Java 8:

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
String dateStr = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date);
System.out.println(dateStr); // prints 2014-10-16 20:12:57
```